# Pause a simple timer

Tags: java, timer, thread-sleep

In Java how would I pause a simple timer?

This may be a bit of newbie question - I'm new to a lot of this.  I have a simple pomodoro timer using `Thread.sleep( MILLISECONDS )` , which runs repeatedly in a for loop, and then chimes using the default system sound (`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();` ) .

I'd like to put a JButton to pause it( I'm using a simple JPanel that shows the pomodoros completed, and at what time.), then show some periods like so  `......` on the JPanel

What is the best way to pause/resume? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `Thread.sleep`. This will block the `EDT` if done on the UI Thread. Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and set the delay to the period interval. `pause/resume` functionality can be achieved using [stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#stop%28%29)/[start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#start%28%29) respectively.